# Creating QueryList of type TemplateRef using ngForOF directive

Tags: angular

Assuming `@ContentChildren` is used in component **A**, targeting `QueryList<TemplateRef>`.

Is it possible for component **B** to use component **A** in its template, passing it as a single `TemplateRef` on which we iterate over using `NgForOf` directive, simply creating `QueryList` of type `NgTemplate` without rendering it, just as we would pass it multiple items of type `NgTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the regular `*ngFor` syntax work perfectly:

```html
<ng-template *ngFor="let action of actions">
```